# How To Use WordPress Rest API v2 Update User Meta

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WordPress 4.8 and trying to update user meta field using rest api built-in. I can update other fields of user but not the meta field of user. I try to POST the following json body to server, but i got no update at all. Hope anyone can show me some example how to do a post request to update user's meta field.

```
URL : http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/100  
method : POST 
content-type: application/json 
body : {"meta":{"meta_key":"meta_value"}} or {"meta": {"key":"meta_key","value":"meta_value"}} or {"meta":[{"meta_key":"meta_value"}]} or {"meta":[{"key":"meta_key","value":"meta_value"}]}
```

Comment: Did you figure out?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by registering the meta value that I wanted to update through the API:

`register_meta('user', 'my_meta_value_name', [
    'type' => 'string',
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
]);`

And then with JavaScript we can update it like:

`var currentUserId = 1;
var apiUrl = '/wp-json/wp/v2/users/' + currentUserId;
var data = {
    'id': currentUserId,
    'meta': {
        'my_meta_value_name': 'new value'
    }
};
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl,
    headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': 'nonce_value_here'},
    data: data
})
.success(function (data) {
    // do stuff
})
.fail(function (data) {
    // do stuff
});`

Comment: does it work without X-WP-Nonce?

Comment: Where should I put the register_meta()?

Answer (score 0):

With Wordpress `Version 6.4.3` I had to do the following:

```php
$userMetaProp = 'customMeta';
add_filter('rest_pre_insert_user', static function (
    stdClass        $prepared_user,
    WP_REST_Request $request
) use ($userMetaProp): stdClass {
    if (!empty($request['meta'])) {
        $prepared_user->{$userMetaProp} = [];
        foreach ($request['meta'] as $key => $value) {
            $prepared_user->{$userMetaProp}[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $prepared_user;
}, accepted_args: 2);
add_filter('insert_custom_user_meta', static function (
    array   $custom_meta,
    WP_User $user,
    bool    $update,
    array   $userdata
) use ($userMetaProp): array {
    if (array_key_exists($userMetaProp, $userdata)) {
        foreach ($userdata[$userMetaProp] as $key => $value) {
            $custom_meta[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $custom_meta;
}, accepted_args: 4);
```

Now you can update user meta data with a request like so:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic [AUTH-TOKEN]' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "meta": {
        "option":"theValueForTheOption"
    }
}'
```

You need to change [AUTH-TOKEN] with your own token (see: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/)

### Explanation:

- the first filter `rest_pre_insert_user` get the data in the meta prop of the request and store it in `$prepared_user`
- the second filter `insert_custom_user_meta` use the data in `$userdata` which get his data from `$prepared_user` to return the custom meta data to store in the user